# UIPageViewController - Fazendo um slider

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone

Estou utilizando uma `UIPageViewController`. A mesma exibe conteúdos e é trocada de página através de um `NSTimer`. Basicamente como os slider de conteúdos em destaques nos sites.
O problema é que eu preciso identificar exatamente para que lado o usuário está movendo a mesma.

Quero lembrar que em muitos dos casos que pesquisei os usuários respondiam de qual maneira eu posso definir a direção ou pelos métodos:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

Quando na verdade eu preciso, diretamente "capturar" este evento para que eu possa adicionar definir propriedades de acordo com a direção.

Obs.: Se por um acaso alguém tenha mais alguma sugestão de outro componente para utilizar em casos como esse, será bem aceita.

Comment: Você precisa saber isso antes ou depois da ação completar? Por [este método](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/UIPageViewControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPageViewControllerDelegate/pageViewController%3adidFinishAnimating%3apreviousViewControllers%3atransitionCompleted%3a) você consegue ter esta resposta.

Comment: Gostaria de ter depois de ter completado a ação de alteração da página